# ESXi Understanding Host Memory vs Guest Memory

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Can someone explain what the difference between Host and Guest Memory is? I see that Host is full so I'm assuming that Guest means it needs an additional 2.24gb. However, I'm thinking it can't be that easy of an explanation.

[image: Memory]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Host memory shows the total memory assigned to that guest by the host.

Guest memory means what host sees as active memory usage on the guest, however this may differ from what you see from guest’s OS.

So you've assigned 16GB to this guest, and it's only using 2.24GB. You should really only give your VMs as much memory as they *need*.

More information in the [vSphere Resource Management](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-resource-management-guide.pdf) documentation.